# Rotate Polygon inside GoogleMap using Android Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, rotation, polygon, google-maps-api-2

I'm migrating a Google Maps API v1 App to the new v2 API and I'm getting some problems with overlays.

First of all, I'm using a MapView instead a MapFragment because I need to control some lifecycle events and add some listeners to the view.

My map rotates according to the current bearing that I'm getting from the orientation sensor.

I want to add a triangle over the map representing a vision field, so the triangle must not rotate with the map. It must be always fixed in the same position.

The problem is that with the new API I have to provide LatLng bounds to the Polygon instead of screen pixels so the Polygon will rotate with the map.

And know, here are my questions:

Is there any way to rotate (-bearing, so it will be always in the same position) a polygon once it's been added to the map?

Is there any other way to get that working? I tried also to add another view over the mapView and use the onDraw method, but its not allowed to add child views within a mapView.

Answer (score 1):

Put your map fragment in the xml layout file within a relative layout, then add a second relative layout and put your image where you would like it on the screen and it will be overlayed without you needing to actually attach it to the map, I hope this helps!